# How do I reference a property in Global.asax from .aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax, inline-code

> The name 'Global' does not exist in the current context

I'm getting the above error when trying to reference a property I've created in Global.asax:

```
public static String ThemeColor
{ get; set; }
```

from the C# on the aspx page (outputting some javascript):

```
alert("<%=Global.ThemeColor %>");
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: You probably need to prefix Global with the namespace in which it has been defined.

Comment: Are you sure the `Global.asax` file is the best place for this?

Comment: I think that javascript runs on the client, and not the server so what I'd do is make an invisible control, and set it's Text property to be "Theme Color", and I'd access that from the javascript

Comment: You should be able to access it using ((global_asax)this.Context.ApplicationInstance).ThemeColor

Comment: Usually the namespace for things in `Global.asax` follow the format of `[ProjectName].Web`. Like EvertonAgner stated, `Global.asax probably isn't the best place for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several options:

- The class name isn't `Global`, Maybe you changed it?
- You are missing the `using` of the namespace

You really should not use the `Global.asax` to handle the theme color.
`css` seems to be a more appropriate place for it...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a separate class of the theme-color and at the application-start event in global.asax set the themecolor to something.

Answer (score 0):

If you're putting these sorts of values in Global.asax you need a doctor.

Create a class called "GlobalSiteValues" or whatever. Make sure the namespace it lives in is either the same as the aspx page, or registered in web.config (or non-existent or use the full name).

Then this will work (once you have set the value, obviously)

```
public class GlobalSiteValues
{
    public static string MyString{ get;set }
    public static int MyInt{ get;set; }
}
```

... and in the aspx page (in script block)...

```
var abc = "<%= GlobalSiteValues.MyString %>";
alert(abc);
```

Or why not set up a "context class" for your site. Like `HttpContext.Current` ?